# re-train stanford nlp pos tagger in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, pos-tagger

i'm pretty new to nlp and i'm trying to figure out pos taggings.
currently i'm trying out the stanford nlp pos tagger, url: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

from the link above, there's this sentence:

> The tagger can be retrained on any language, given POS-annotated
>   training text for the language.

However, I'm not able to get it working. All I can do now is to give it a text file to tag. for e.g. `String test = "this is a test";` will return me this_DT is_VBZ a_DT test_NN.

How can I go about retraining the tagger? Let's say I want the above string to be returned as this_DT is_VBZ a_DT test_VB?

appreciate any answers here.

Comment: Well in the above example, 'test' is a noun, making that the correct tagging. Do you mean training to differentiate between noun and verb?

Comment: hi hacket, thanks for the reply. no i do not mean to differentiate between noun and verb. simply put, how do i re-train the tagger if the output tags is not the one i wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a POS tagged corpus with many examples of the phenomenon/phenomena you are looking to correct, you will likely not have any success retraining the tagger models.  To clarify, based on how I expect the Stanford tools do training, there is no mechanism to add single examples to alter the models.  You will need to have a complete corpus and retrain anew.

If you do indeed have a corpus, then I would refer to this [previously posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156256/how-do-i-create-my-own-training-corpus-for-stanford-tagger) to get details on the file format and proper steps for training the Stanford CoreNLP models.

Otherwise, you best bet is to write some post-processing rules / regex patterns that override the behavior. A use for such rules is to ensure people and places in a wordlist are tagged as proper nouns (NNP).

Good luck!